# Remote kernel lost internet connection

Tags: front-end, kernel, remote-access

I'm running a calculation on a remote kernel and the internet connection is interrupted. When it recovered, all definitions were lost on the front end. Does the kernel on the remote machine automatically stop when it loses contact with the front end? Or is it possible to re-establish the connection? I see about 10 kernels (`*/WolframKernel`) running on the remote machine but I'm not sure how to identify which one is mine.